# React - how to Redirect path after completing POST request using fetch

Tags: reactjs, redirect, async-await, react-router, fetch

I am trying to redirect to another path **AFTER** completing a POST request using fetch.

I have set a variable in my state to watch for after the POST function completes

`this.state.successfulPOST: false`

and I am conditional rendering, so if i `this.state.successfulPOST: true`, my redirect gets rendered

The problem is that my redirect happens **before** my POST request. How can I make it so that my POST request for `/api/account/update/` is finished then render my redirect for my GET request on this path`/checkout/shippingaddress`?

Here is my full code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "whatwg-fetch";
import cookie from "react-cookies";
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

class GuestEmailForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      successfulPOST: false,
    };
  }

  updateGuestEmail = (data) => {

    const endpoint = "/api/account/update/"; 
    const csrfToken = cookie.load("csrftoken");

    if (csrfToken !== undefined) {
      let lookupOptions = {
        method: "POST",
        redirect: 'follow',
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "X-CSRFToken": csrfToken
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        credentials: "include"
      };
      fetch(endpoint, lookupOptions)
        .then(response => {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(responseData => {
          this.setState({email: responseData.email})
        })
        .then( 
          this.setState({successfulPOST: true})
          )
        .catch(error => {
          console.log("error", error);
          alert("An error occured, please try again later.");
        });
    }
  };


  handleEmailChange = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  };

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let data = this.state;

    if (data !== undefined){
        (
          this.updateGuestEmail(data),
          console.log(this.state.email)
        )
    } else {
        ""
    }
  };

  resetSucessfulPOST = () => {
      this.setState({
        successfulPOST: false,
      })
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    this.resetSucessfulPOST()
  }

  render() {

    const {email, successfulPOST} = this.state

    // redirect to shipping page after successful POST of email
    if (successfulPOST === true)  

      return <Redirect push to={{ pathname: '/checkout/shippingaddress'}} />

    else

      return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <div>            
              <label>
                  Guest Email:
                  <input 
                          className="input" 
                          type="email" 
                          name="email"
                          value={email} 
                          onChange={event => {
                              this.handleEmailChange(event);
                            }}
                          />
              </label>
              <button className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

              </div>

        </form>
    );
  }
}

export default GuestEmailForm;
```

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to figure out the problem.

instead of this `.then(this.setState({successfulPOST: true}))`

it needs to be this 
`.then(responseData => {this.setState({successfulPOST: true,});})`

turn out if you don't passing an argument into the `.then()` the promise aspect doesn't work and my setState gets called immediately.

Answer (score 0):

First you should remove the `componentDidMount()` method then
you will

```
setState({successfulPOST: true})
```

at the end of updateGuestEmail method then it will re-render and according to your condition it will redirect..

Comment: Thanks but my re-rendering is working fine. The problem is how can I make it so that my POST request for /api/account/update/ is finished then render my redirect for my GET request on this path/checkout/shippingaddress? Right now the GET request is happening before the POST request and messing things up in the backend.